# rotation in latest OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl

How do I rotate a triangle, given that rotation in latest OpenGL is deprecated? Before deprecation:

```
    gl.glRotated(i, 0, 0, 1);

    gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES);       
    gl.glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );   
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f ); 
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f );  
    gl.glEnd();
```

I tried doing this, it's just a translation though:

```
    double rotCos = Math.cos(i);
    double rotSine = Math.sin(i);


    gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES);       
    gl.glVertex3d(0.0f + rotSine, 1.0f + rotCos, 0.0f );    
    gl.glVertex3d(-1.0f + rotSine, -1.0f + rotCos, 0.0f );  
    gl.glVertex3d(1.0f + rotSine, -1.0f + rotCos, 0.0f );   
    gl.glEnd();
```

How to achieve the math behind glRotated?

Comment: I've been out of the OpenGL loop for a while, but I think this is where you're supposed to use matrix transformations: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html

Answer (score 4):

What you did is not what the idea behind the deprecation of those function was; this deprecation included the functions *glBegin*, *glVertex* and *glEnd*, too, so if you're using those, you're missing the point

What you should to is implement a vertex shader, in which you perform the usual steps of vertex transformation i.e. multiply the vertex with first a modelview, then a projection matrix; you can also contract modelview and projection into one matrix, but this makes things a bit trickier regarding illumination.

The matrices are passed to OpenGL through so called *uniforms*. To create the matrices use some vector math library like GLM or Eigen (with the unofficial OpenGL module accompanying Eigen).

Answer (score 1):

> How to achieve the math behind glRotated?

The matrix `glRotate()` constructs is right there [in the documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glRotate.xml#description).

Answer (score 0):

It is still OK to use depreciated functions, but if you want to use "modern" OpenGL (OpenGL 3 and higher) you are going to have to do things rather differently.

For one, you no longer use `glBegin`/`glEnd` and instead draw everything using vertex buffer objects. Secondly, the fixed function pipeline has been removed so vertex and fragment shaders are required to draw anything. There are also number of other changes (including the addition of vertex array objects, and geometry shaders).

The way to do rotation in OpenGL 3 is to pass modelView and projection matrices in uniforms, and use them to compute vertex positions in the vertex shader.

Ultimately, if you want to learn "modern" OpenGL, you are probably best off just looking online for tutorials on OpenGL 3.0 (or higher).